# Real-time video streaming with OpenCV and React JS

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, opencv, yolo, object-recognition

I have developed a real-time object recognition code using YOLO and openCV. I want to stream the video out of the python program via web in real-time. Also I have designed a ReactJS based web application to control my raspberry PI. Is there any way to play this video out from openCV in the web application?

I came across opencv.js, but the framerate with it was too low compared to what I got in python. I also tried tensorflow model (coco-ssd) but it wasnt very accurate. Any suggestions? or any other way to find a solution for the problem?

The yolo model I am running is yolov3-tiny.